# AWS Cloud Formation - Requested configuration not supported AWS::EC2::Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I am getting below error on one of my cloud formation template -

> 13:00:10 UTC+0550 CREATE_FAILED   AWS::EC2::Instance  WebApplicationServer    The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.

My CloudFormation template is -

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Parameters": {
    "DevServerKeyPair": {
        "Description": "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance",
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
        "ConstraintDescription": "Must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
    }
},
"Resources": {
    "DevVpc": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
        "Properties": {
            "CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/16",
            "EnableDnsSupport": "false",
            "EnableDnsHostnames": "false",
            "InstanceTenancy": "dedicated",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "DevStackVpc"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "DevSubnet": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
        "Properties": {
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "DevVpc"
            },
            "CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/16",
            "AvailabilityZone": {
                "Fn::Select": [
                    0,
                    {
                        "Fn::GetAZs": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "WebApplicationServerSG": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
        "Properties": {
            "VpcId": {
                "Ref": "DevVpc"
            },
            "GroupDescription": "Enable HTTP, HTTPS and SSH access",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "WebApplicationServer Service Group"
                }
            ],
            "SecurityGroupIngress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "443",
                    "ToPort": "443",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "ToPort": "80",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "22",
                    "ToPort": "22",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }
            ],
            "SecurityGroupEgress": [
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "443",
                    "ToPort": "443",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "80",
                    "ToPort": "80",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                },
                {
                    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                    "FromPort": "22",
                    "ToPort": "22",
                    "CidrIp": "0.0.0.0/0"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "WebApplicationServer": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
        "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-f3e5aa9c",
            "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": "WebApplicationServer"
                }
            ],
            "KeyName": {
                "Ref": "DevServerKeyPair"
            },
            "NetworkInterfaces": [
                {
                    "SubnetId": {"Ref": "DevSubnet"},
                    "AssociatePublicIpAddress": "true",
                    "DeviceIndex": "0",
                    "GroupSet": [{ "Ref" : "WebApplicationServerSG" }]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to diagnose it but failed to understand which particular configuration in this simple template is not supported currently. Any help or pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to launch an instance directly with the ami-id used here? Basically, the same configurations specified in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your VPC has an instance tenancy of dedicated, however t2 instances cannot be launched as [dedicated instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html). You will need to pick a different instance type or switch the tenancy of your VPC.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't have tenancy dedicated. The reason was I tried to use the instance type which is too new (`r6g`) and is missing in my region. So the solution was to fall back to older one (`r5a`).

Answer (score -1):

Looks problem with subnet creation with fn::select function.

```
"DevSubnet" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Subnet",
  "Properties" : {
    "VpcId" : { "Ref" : "DevVpc" },
    "CidrBlock" : "172.31.0.0/16",
    "AvailabilityZone" : {
      "Fn::Select" : [ "0", { "Fn::GetAZs" :""} ]
    }
  }
}
```

Try this. I hope it will work.

Comment: There is no difference apart from making whole select function in one line, both are valid json syntax hence makes no difference.